# Find size of screen in characters (columns and lines)

Tags: x11, xfce, xterm, xfce4-terminal

On geometry the `X` man page says:

> "GEOMETRY SPECIFICATIONS: ... most X programs accept a command line argument of the form -geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF (where WIDTH, HEIGHT, XOFF, and YOFF are numbers) for specifying a preferred size and location for  this  application's main window. The WIDTH and HEIGHT parts of the geometry specification are usually measured in either pixels or characters, depending on the application ..."

Seems for both `xterm` and `xfce4-terminal` the WIDTH and HEIGHT of `-geometry` option are in units of characters. In order to launch such a terminal with a specific geometry relative to the screen **programatically** (example, tiling: cover each quadrant with a terminal window) I need to know the size of the screen in units of characters. I can find in pixels with `xwininfo -root` but can't figure out how to find in character units. How do do this? Answer specific to XFCE4 would be fine.

Comment: `xwininfo` also doesn't tell you the usable dimensions (e.g you have to subtract some for borders, scrollbars, window decorations, menu bars and such). And it also depends on the size of your font. But you can always open an `xterm` and resize it: it'll tell you its geometry in characters while you are resizing it, so just remember the numbers when you are happy with it and let go of the mouse button. I just found out however that the offsets are in pixels, so I have to say `xterm -geometry 104x32+960+540` to get one that's a quarter size and placed in the lower right quadrant of my screen.

Comment: I want to do this programatically. For example, script to start 4 different networking monitoring tools and tile terminals over screen. You right about having to account for things like panels but I guess close enough is good enough as a first step. Yes the pixel to character unit conversion depends on the font. And yes it is rather odd that xoff, yoff are in pixels but w, h are in characters!

Comment: If you're running a shell inside the terminal, you can use `tput cols` and `tput lines` (if ncurses is installed). Not sure if it's possible to do it from outside a shell running in the terminal in question, though.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous, was aware of `tput cols|lines`. A tput option analoguous to xwininfo's  `-root` would be perfect but AFAIK not such thing exists. I think `tput` is never going to be window manager aware - as far as it's concerned there is just one terminal screen and that's that.

Comment: Is this question really "how do I find out the dimensions of the character cells xterm will use before I launch it?", or is finding the screen dimensions *in* some sort of abstract characters material?

Comment: For xterm I imagine this is *possible* through X resources (and possibly font-parsing), but for xfce-terminal presumably those are regular internal application settings. Is addressing *both at once* necessary?

Comment: @MichaelHomer yes finding the character cell dimensions in pixels is a path to an answer given we known the screen dimension in pixels. Prefer xfce terminal but if I have to use xterm or something similar for this that would do.

Comment: You might find [wmctrl](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl) useful: it allows you to place and resize windows, move them to other desktops and many other things - and it can be used in scripts.  I'm using Fedora 34 and it is packaged by the distro.

Comment: @NickD, indeed wmctrl seems useful. Thanks. I've been experimenting but it seems a bit flaky, Specifically, seems like the window ids are not stable. Example `wmctrl -r 0x01801b8c  -e 0,0,0,120,120` will work only sometimes and when it does on the wrong window.

Comment: You need `-i` I think to use window IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question: Using `wmctrl` as suggested by @NickD came up with a hacky solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

get_window_id() { # Convert window title into wmctrl window id
  wmctrl -l | grep "$1" | cut -f1 -d" " | tail -n1
}

screen_dim=( $(xwininfo -root | grep "\-geometry" | sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\+0\+0/\1 \2/gp' -n) )

w=$((screen_dim[0] / 2))
h=$((screen_dim[1] / 2))
k=40

xfce4-terminal --title="My Window 1"
xfce4-terminal --title="My Window 2"
xfce4-terminal --title="My Window 3"
xfce4-terminal --title="My Window 4"

wmctrl -i -r $(get_window_id "My Window 1") -e 0,0,0,$w,$((h - k))
wmctrl -i -r $(get_window_id "My Window 2") -e 0,$w,0,$w,$((h - k))
wmctrl -i -r $(get_window_id "My Window 3") -e 0,0,$h,$w,$((h - k))
wmctrl -i -r $(get_window_id "My Window 4") -e 0,$w,$h,$w,$((h - k))
```

The `k` parameter is a crude adjustment to account for task bar issue as also mentioned by @NickD.

If I could somehow find the pixel dimensions of a character could just pass geometry straight to xfce4-terminal, which is a bit cleaner:

```bsh
screen_dim=( $(xwininfo -root | grep "\-geometry" | sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\+0\+0/\1 \2/gp' -n) )
w=$((screen_dim[0] / 2))
h=$((screen_dim[1] / 2))
cw=$((c/character_width))
ch=$((h/character_height))
k=1
xfce4-terminal --title="My Window 1" --geometry=${cw}x${ch}+0+0
...
```

But can't figure out how to get `character_width`, `character_height`.

Comment: Alas, character width and height of your xfce4-terminal depend on the font settings of your  xfce4-terminal. What you would need is a way to interrogate xfce4-terminal for these settings before you start the actual xfce4-terminal terminal window. Such a feature is probably not going to be implemented ever. Until then, and once you settle for a particular terminal font and font size, you could manually determine width and height in characters of a full screen terminal window, and put these for instance in your login script for central reference.